# Webscrapping failure using python

Tags: web-scraping

I am try to get the text in the 'Description' section of this website: https://www7.fdic.gov/DICT/app/templates/Index.html#!/Details/AATOTFV/FTS/FI

I am using this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www7.fdic.gov/DICT/app/templates/Index.html#!/Details/AATOTFV/FTS/FI"
print(url)
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
div_element = soup.find("div", class_ ="col-sm-12 data-col-custom")
print(div_element)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve your questions. What exactly is the issue and what error do you get? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in the RIS Data Definition table are updated through AJAX, so requesting the webpage directly as the given code, won't be able to fetch. (You can go the page source to see the actual HTML of the page, before AJAX).

I have updated the code, with AJAX request URL created from this RIS element URL, and the description element is in the `DEFINES` key on the response JSON output.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page_url = "https://www7.fdic.gov/DICT/app/templates/Index.html#!/Details/AATOTFV/FTS/FI"

ajax_url = f"https://www7.fdic.gov/dict/api/MiniSpec?orgtypecde={page_url.split('/')[-1]}&risdb={page_url.split('/')[-2]}&risname={page_url.split('/')[-3]}"
print(ajax_url)
headers = {
    "Host": "www7.fdic.gov"
}

response = requests.get(ajax_url, headers=headers)
print(BeautifulSoup(response.json()['DEFINES'], 'html5lib').text)
```

Here's the updated code.

And the output of the given code is:

```
https://www7.fdic.gov/dict/api/MiniSpec?orgtypecde=FI&risdb=FTS&risname=AATOTFV
ASSETS MEASURED AT FAIR VALUE ON A RECURRING BASIS:  AGGREGATE                                      AMOUNT OF FAIR VALUE OPTION ASSETS.                                                                                                                                                                     NOTE:                                                                                                                                                                                                   (1)  REPORTED BY FORM 051 FILERS WHO INDICATE ON SCHEDULE SU THAT                                   THE INSTITUTION USES THE FV OPTION TO MEASURE ANY OF ITS ASSETS.                                                                                                                                        (2)  EXCLUDES AVAILABLE-FOR-SALE SECURITIES, TRADING ASSETS, AND                                    DERIVATIVE CONTRACTS (SEE CALL REPORT INSTRUCTIONS).
```